# "item not found" in-app billing for subscription

Tags: android

I am working on in-app billing for subscription and i follow all the step as mention in developer docs. i also test for in-app billing and its working fine.but when i change it for subscription then its give error.

```
E/Volley(1384): [157] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/details?doc=subs:com.test.app:subscription_monthly
```

can i put product id same as in Managed ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you published your app and subscription item?

Comment: @Jin35 you don't need to publish the application, only the items and add yourself as a test account (must be the first gmail entered to the device).

Comment: Are you sure you use correct purchase id?

Comment: @liorry why i got this error ?

Comment: @Jin35 ..yes...but i am not use this product id in my code.

Comment: I paste the link at web browser and It can't load this page too. Please check if the link is correct or not.

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh u can't open this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that (and I already noticed it) subscription test items (made by google for testing purpose) are not working. Only normal purchase, cancel, refund are actually working

Comment: can i put product id for subscription same as  purchase id ?

Comment: Nope. Because purchaseID will return a purchase and all callback will be about purchase. I think that you have to fill a bugrequest on android bugtracker. Also those are "special" ids made by google only for test purpose